# corosync nodes not online together (one offline, one online)

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker

I have setup two cluster nodes for HA using corosync, pacemaker and crmsh. Now all the services are up and I found a problem that two machines are not syncing properly, because of that both applications and VIP are running in parallel. How can I sync these applications?
And this is my /etc/corosync/corosync.conf

```
    compatibility: whitetank

    aisexec {
        # Run as root - this is necessary to be able to manage resources with Pacemaker
        user: root
        group: root
    }
    service {
        # Load the Pacemaker Cluster Resource Manager
        ver: 1
        name: pacemaker
        use_mgmtd: no
        use_logd: no
    }
    totem {
            version: 2
            secauth: off
            interface {
                    member {
                            memberaddr: 10.193.30.16
                    }
                    member {
                            memberaddr: 10.193.30.22
                    }
                    ringnumber: 0
                    bindnetaddr: 10.193.30.31
                    mcastaddr: 255.255.255.224
                    mcastport: 5405
            }
            transport: udpu
    }
    logging {
        fileline: on
        to_stderr: yes
        to_logfile: yes
        to_syslog: yes
        logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
        debug: on
        timestamp: on

        logger_subsys {
        subsys: AMF
        debug: off
        }
    }
    amf {
        mode: disabled
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change:

```
bindnetaddr: 10.193.30.31 ==> bindnetaddr: 10.193.30.0
mcastaddr: 255.255.255.224 ==> mcastaddr: 226.94.1.1
```